# VB.Net Dataset checking null

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, null, dataset

Using vb.net and sql server

so I the dataset like this:

```
Dim ds3 As New FOCUSDataSetTableAdapters.GajiTableAdapter
```

and I want to get the item in the dataset into an array. but the dataset is empty for now.. so I try..

```
Dim smp As New List(Of String)()

 Try
  For i = 0 To ds3.GetData.Count - 1
   If (ds3.GetData.Rows(0).Item(3) Is Nothing) Then
    smp.Add("0")
  End If

   Next
      Catch ex As Exception
        i = i - 1

        End Try
```

So basically what I want is.. If the database is null/empty then add the "0" to array. But everytime I run this code it only gives me error state that there is now row at current position (0)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should by something like this (maybe it is necessary to do more modification - your snippet cannot be tested):

```
Try
  dim tbl as DataTable=ds3.GetData()
  For i = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
   If (tbl.Rows(i).Item(3) Is DBNull.Value) Then
    smp.Add("0")
   End If

  Next
 Catch ex As Exception
        i = i - 1 'rather strange and probably causes endless loop

End Try
```

You should by aware that `GetData` method returns a DataTable and you want to iterate it.
 Reconsider your errorhandling!

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess (and I would be guessing) that the dataset is not only empty, but has never been set up. This would result in a null exception in the `ds3.GetData.Count` method.

Try running this in debug, and check the value of `ds3` and the message in the `ex`.